# Facebook sdk.js error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use facebook api to get shares count for my site. Everything works fine if I logged in under my account. But If user logged under different account, then he gets error in facebook sdk.js file.

> sdk.js:formatted:4150Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined(…)

I made my app public and I don't know what else to do.
Here's my code

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '1836193963304496',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
  };
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        var url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/?access_token="+accessToken+"&format=json&id="+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+"&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1"
        $.get(url,{},function(response){
            if(response.share.share_count>0){
                $(".social-likes__counter_facebook").html(response.share.share_count).removeClass('social-likes__counter_empty');
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: debug the response of getLoginStatus: console.log(response). what´s in there?

Comment: It says that I'm not authorized

Comment: well...what does that tell you?

Comment: btw, why are you using jquery get for the api call, and not the js sdk? you could also just use querySelector instead, and innerHTML, no dependency on jquery with the same amount of code.

Comment: ok, now i understand what you want to achieve...well, that is the wrong way. i will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only get an Access Token with the JS SDK if you authorize the user with `FB.login` first. I assume you don´t want to do that, because you just want to show the like count of an URL. The correct way to do this is to use an App Access Token, but you MUST use it server side, NOT with JavaScript on the client. You need to keep the Token secret, and you should also implement caching on your server or you will get to an API limit with too many users.

More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/